# How do I get JSON data and load it in a JavaScript file? (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Oh? Hi there!

**So, I had a little problem recently**.

I'm probably too dumb to realize how to do this, but here it is. I need some sort of way to actually read JSON files. I am requiring them, but I have no idea how to actually use them.

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "help": "Displays this message"
}
```

And my code here:

```
const cmdh = require("../cmdhandle");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const util = require("../../util");
const json = require("../help.json");

module.exports = {
    aliases: ["?"],
    execute:function(msg, cmd) {
        // Insert code here so that "def" is a list of elements and definitions in the json file
        msg.channel.send(util.genEmbed("Help", def, "#ff5c5c"));
    }
}
```

Edit: ;p i was an idiot back then, looks like this was wayyy easier than i thought lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already loaded the JSON with `const json = require("../help.json")`, now all you have to do to use the stuff in it is to type `json.help` or `json["help"]`.

If you want a list of the definitions and elements, you can use the `Object.keys` and `Object.values` functions, or `Object.entries` for key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cmdh = require("../cmdhandle");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const util = require("../../util");
const json = require("../help.json");

module.exports = {
    aliases: ["?"],
    execute:function(msg, cmd) {
        // Get all entires
        Object.entries(json).forEach(([key, msg]) => {
            msg.channel.send(util.genEmbed(key, msg, "#ff5c5c"));
        })
    }
}
```